# Jquery slideToogle to right

Tags: html, slide, right-to-left

I have this very simple code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      

   $('.content>div').hide();      

   $('.content>h3').click(function() {      
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');      
      $(this).toggleClass('active');      
   });  

});
```

it causes of course that my div slides out from top to bottom. Could you help me add to this code or command the line that in result it will be slide out from right to left??

Answer (score 0):

`.slideToggle()` animates the height of the matched elements so you will likely have to rely on a different function/method - but this is not that difficult. You can do this either in JavaScript or use CSS3 animation properties. Depends on the use case but I'd probably use the CSS3 option because it is hardware accelerated on most devices so it is smoother.

Here's a simple sketch how that could be done

In the JavaScript file:

```
$('.content>h3').click(function() {   
  // just switch the class 'open' the rest is defined in CSS   
  $(this).next().toggleClass('open');       
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
```

});

And in the CSS file:

```
.content div {
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: width 1s ease-out;
}
.content div.open {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Example:
 
http://jsbin.com/qebigohu/2/ (preview)
http://jsbin.com/qebigohu/2/edit (code)